# Can we disable Always block using disable statement?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

```
module xyz;
  
  always
  begin : b1
    $display("I am executing"); // statement 1
    disable b1;
    $display("I am still executing"); // statement 2    
  end  
  
endmodule
```

I am unable to understand how disable statement actually behaves in the above code.

I was expecting that the `statement 1` will execute only once and then the always block (b1) will be disabled forever.
But actually `statement 1` is being executed infinitely (until the process is killed) and `statement 2` is being skipped.

```
I am executing
I am executing
I am executing
      .
      .
      .
```

I have tried all simulators of EDA Playground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `disable` *name* statement is essentially a *jump* to the `end` of the named block. It does not terminate any processes (except nested fork/join blocks)

The `always` construct creates a permanent process that executes the procedural statement that follows it. Once that statement completes, it executes it over again indefinitely. In your example, that procedural statement is a `begin/end` block